# Renaming/replacing ShortCut During Inno Setup Installation

Tags: inno-setup

The [InstallDelete] Section enables files to be deleted but does not enable icons to be deleted (the only Type supported is files, I was hoping it also supported icons).

I need to change the shortcuts that are associated the programs being installed. I can add a new shortcut (e.g. 'Maintenance') by adding the appropriate parameters to the [Icons] section but have not found a way of removing the old shortcut (e.g. 'Repair').

Has anyone got any ideas how this can be acheived without delving into the Registry - I am familiar (but certainly not an expert) in the use of Pascal Scripting.

Answer (score 3):

"Icon" aka Shortcut is just .lnk file placed somewhere - e.g. on your Desktop - pointing to other file - e.g. `Program.exe`  - in `{app}` directory.

If you create such "icon" in `[Icons]` section it is automatically deleted during uninstall (unless the `uninsneveruninstall` Flag is set).

If you have some "icon" which you want to delete then simply delete the .lnk file from destination folder (e.g. Desktop).
You can do that in `[InstallDelete]` or `[UninstallDelete]` or programatically in `[Code]` section:

```
[InstallDelete]
Type: files; Name: "{commondesktop}\My Program.lnk"
```

where `"{commondesktop}\My Program.lnk"` is the path\name of the icon (actually the name of the .lnk file) to delete.

Comment: Thank you very much indeed. Success!, however I did have to include the .lnk extension before it would find and delete the shortcut.

Comment: You do need to specify the `.lnk` extension when deleting the file else it won't find it.